# Find a specified audio pattern in a collection of audio files

Tags: audio

I have a collection of 1000 audio files. Those files are music files stored in MP3 format, some are 10 minutes long, some are 15 seconds long.

I also have one audio file that is 1 second long, also in MP3. I would like to find which files from my collection contain this 1-second audio file. This 1-second audio file can have a slightly worse audio quality than my collection, because it was recoded, recompressed, etc, so I would need some more intelligent comparison method than simple binary search through my collection of files.

What should I read about if I'd like to create a small program for searching through my collection of audio files for this 1-second audio pattern?

**Edit**: In other words: Each file in my collection of 1000 files is a song. This 1-second fragment I'm searching for is a fragment of some song from this collection, and I'd like to know what song it's taken from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `len(audioSegment)` feaure of [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

"../so/*.mp3" holds your audio files. Or you can iterate through various folders using `glob`.

```
from glob import glob
from pydub import AudioSegment

for mp3_file in glob("../so/*.mp3"):
  tmpAudioSegment = AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file)
   #Note: pydub len returns in milliseconds.
  print("{}  :  {}".format(mp3_file,len(tmpAudioSegment)/1000))
```

Result

```
../so/Bubbles.mp3  :  10 sec
../so/Drone Dark Suspense 2.mp3  :  30 sec
../so/Sci-Fi Sweep.mp3  :  8 sec
../so/Pinball Machine.mp3  :  22 sec
../so/Title Flange Sweep Hit.mp3  :  3 sec
../so/Whale Sounds.mp3  :  6 sec
../so/Ambient Hit.mp3  :  2 sec
../so/Golf Hit 3.mp3  :  1 sec
```

Comment: I've updated the question with more information what my problem is. If I understand your solution correctly, it would apply if I'd like to search for 1-second songs in my collection of mp3 files. But I'd like to match the 1-second mp3 pattern in all my collection of files, and all of those files are longer than 1 second. This would mean that one of the matches could be i.e. file number 537, which has a duration of 5:30min, position 0:13sec. This match would tell me that in the 13th second of file 537, there is an audio pattern that matches my 1-second file.

Comment: What u r looking for is "audio fingerprinting" , checkout https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu  that has detailed implementation. Try it out and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: It looks like that's what I was looking for indeed!